# Pandas Taking the Nlargest ignoring 0

Tags: pandas

Hi is there a way in Pandas to do nlargest but only take values excluding 0? For example if we have [5, 0, 0] and we want to take the 2 largest, then it would only return 5 because the other values are 0?

Comment: My problem precisely. +1 for a helpful question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the value 0 before you do nlargest:

```
l = pd.Series([5,0,0])
l[l != 0].nlargest(2)

0    5
dtype: int64
```

Similarly, if you have a list of numbers you want to exclude:

```
l[~l.isin(list_of_excluded_numbers)].nlargest(2)
```